# Expression to always subtract if the value is negative, but add if positive?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there an expression or rule that can be applied that would tell the person completing the equation that if a value is negative you need to subtract the negative, but if it is positive you need to add the positive? Basically, you need to match the sign to the negative or positive value of the number.

e.g. if $n$ is a negative number then the equation would read $f(x)=x-n$, but if $n$ is positive the equation would read $f(x)=x+n$.

Comment: Consider $f(x)=x+|n|$

Comment: $f(x)=x+|n|$. You add the absolute value

Comment: Now that you say that, it's obvious. Thank you!

Comment: @mkinson Please either delete the question post an answer  yourself and accept it so the question does not linger on the unanswered queue.

Comment: I can't delete it, I tried. I added a vote to close. It will take 2 days before I can accept "my own" answer (@Prem and @Andrei)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @Prem and @Andrei already, I simply need to add the absolute value of n. Simple, and efficient.